# When does linux set the computer's correct time?

Tags: linux, shell, date, cron

In a Linux CentOS 5 machine, I am running process.sh using a cronjob at @reboot, every day (the machine gets shut off every night and turned on every morning).

process.sh takes the 'date' of the computer, and writes it to a log file, then exits.

When I check the logfile, the timestamp in it says "Tue Jan 1 13:14:38 GMT 2008"

When I go to the console of the computer and give it the 'date' command, it prints the correct date.

My best guess is that my cronjob is running BEFORE the computer sets its correct time.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can we see your shell script and date invocation ?

Comment: most probably, the server gets the "right time" from an external server using NTP. I think your script should check if ntpd is running first.

Comment: also, you could use ntpq instead (see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-is-ntp-client-working/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The battery that powers the CMOS memory on your motherboard may have run out.  Try replacing it by a fresh one.  It should look something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Button_cell).

This advice is based on the fact that the date of your log entry is "Jan 1 2008" which looks conspicuously like an [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) your motherboard may use.  However, the time-of-day 13:14:38 is a little off for this; while the 13 hour shift can be explained if you are in the correct time zone, the nearly 15 minute offset seems odd.  Unless your computer takes that long to boot to the point where cron executes your job.  And of course, the reason why you eventually see the correct time is probably that ntp fixed the system time, as others have noted.